# svn doesn't want to ask for password

Tags: linux, svn, svnserve

My config:

```
root@/var/svn/skryb/conf# cat /etc/init.d/svnserve
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access=read
auth-access=write
password-db = passwd
[sasl]
```

restarting svnserve to make sure it works:

```
# killall svnserve
# /etc/init.d/svnserve
# ps fax | grep svnserve
 1233 pts/2    S+     0:00                      \_ grep svnserve
 1231 ?        Ss     0:00 svnserve -d -r /var/svn/skryb/
```

checking out contents from windows pc:

```
C:\Temp\some>del *.*
C:\Temp\some\*.*, Продолжить [Y(да)/N(нет)]? y

C:\Temp\some>svn co svn://192.168.1.36
A    utils
A    utils\utils.ipr
A    utils\getContents
svn: E200015: Caught signal -- I hit ctr-break here
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about why it does not prompt, but here are some hints, what could be missing.

- When reading the SVN red book: [Create a users file and realm](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth.users), there is missing the entry `realm = <your name>`.
- You don't have mentioned the contents of your `password-db` file. Do you have created it, and does it have the structure:

  ```
  [users]
  <name> = <password>
  ```
- You should remove one the rules `auth-access`, I think the one with `read`, both rules does not make sense.
- I don't have experience with SASL, but the section: [Authentication with SASL](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sasl.authn) mentions at least the following contents:

  ```
  [sasl]
  use-sasl = true
  ```
- Have you checked that your password is not cached? There should be a local cache (in Windows normally located under `%APPDATA%/Subversion/auth/`), this has to be empty when you try to see the password.

When you have tried the hints, comment the result, so I can refine the answer further. I hope they help ...